# Hosting NestJS app on Phusion Passenger when hosting provider expects app.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

I am currently working on a project related to my university and I would like people from my organization to be able to see my progress. My hosting provides the ability to run Node.js server, however it's refering to the app.js file which NestJS project doesn't have as it's being run through the command line (*npm run start*). Is there any way to run such application, for example by creating an app.js file which would be able to run the command?

Thank you for any assistance with this case.

PS. Server is running Phusion Passenger.
[Phusion Passenger error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yT5gQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the server expects an `app.js` file and can't be customized to use something else, then you could have an `app.js` in your root directory that `requires('./dist/main.js')` and that's it. This would mean that your hosting service has to build the typescript code to javascript first, but that's hopefully something supported. If it isn't then you can do

```js
// app.js
require('ts-node').register(); // you can pass extra options here
require('./src/main.ts');
```

It's not something I'd immediately recommend, but it would make the project runnable.